# C# many to two relationship mapping

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, relational-database

I have a Player class and a game class. Where a game has two players.

I created the data model by having a PlayerOne and PlayerTwo object within the game and a Player class has a collection of Games.

The alternative is to have a PlayerGames table with a column for each PlayerIds and the GameId. Is there a preferred option of the two?

It's not a standard many to many and I have to hold which player is one and two for scoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create double many-to-one relationship. Just add two foreign keys e.g. PlayerOne_id, PlayerTwo_id to your Game table. In other words you create Game class with two properties PlayerOne and PlayerTwo. That should generate proper db structure.

Comment: So there is no need to a player games table?

Comment: If you're sure there will always be two players - yes, you don't need a junction table.

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
Games: {game_id, player1_id, player2_id}
Players: {player_id, name}
```